# setting development environment of Heroku template java application

Tags: java, plugins, heroku, eclipse-plugin, local

I have installed Heroku java plug-in and trying to set example application i.e. "Web & Asynchronous worker with Spring, CloudAMQP". This project is following maven and application gets deployed on heroku thru maven.

Would it be possible to run same application using local java container, rabbitmq and worker running in same and/or different JVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Foreman will start any project that has a Procfile. If there are multiple processes defined it will start them all.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#developing-locally-with-foreman

You'll have to build the project locally with Maven first. You can either set the config info for your rabbitmq instance into environment variable or save them in a .env file which foreman will pick up. You can look at your Heroku app with 'heroku config' to see the variables that the app is expecting.